# Android : ClassNotFoundException BootstrapApplication installing APK manually

Tags: android, gradle, apk, classnotfoundexception

I'm having trouble installing manually an APK on an Android phone (tested on several Android versions).
The stacktrace shows me a **ClassNotFoundException** because it can't find the class **BootstrapApplication**.

When I install the APK from Android Studio ("run"), I'm not getting this error.

How can I solve this issue please?

Here is the full stackTrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: mypackage.myapp, PID: 19686
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mypackage.myapp.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/mypackage.myapp, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4745)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:170)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/mypackage.myapp.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/mypackage.myapp, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:170) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I did some research, I think the problem is from the gradle but I can't handle it, so here is the module:app's gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.2.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://an.url'
        credentials {
            username = '********'
            password = '********'
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        defaultPublishConfig 'develop'
        publishNonDefault true
        applicationId "mypackage.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        develop {
            versionNameSuffix '-develop'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        qualif {
            versionNameSuffix '-develop'
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    // To avoid error of jackson "duplicate files copied in apk meta-inf/license"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

    // Android annotations
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    // Android annotation modules
    compile "org.androidannotations:rest-spring-api:$AAVersion"
    apt "org.androidannotations:rest-spring:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"
    apt "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    // Use ormlite DAO
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'

    // Use jackson rest converter
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.0'

    // Maply
    compile 'com.mousebirdconsulting.maply:Android:2.5'

    // Google play services for geolocation
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'

    // Dependant modules of Wizway
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

    // ACRA for bug report
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'
}
apt {
    arguments {
        // you can set annotation processing options here
        logLevel 'TRACE'
        logAppenderConsole 'true'
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with installing manually? do you use a Gradle Task for installation? do you want to install the debug or the release version?

Comment: I mean copy the apk from generated folder of the project, and paste it into the smartphone, then I install it. I want the release version